# scanf reads every double wrong

Tags: c, double, scanf, lf

I have the following code:

```
    int main(void)
{
    double r;
    scanf("lf",&r);
    printf("%lf\n",r);
}
```

Any value I enter returns a nonsense-number with about 40-50 digits. scanf works fine with chars, integers, strings etc., but with doubles I get this problem.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: Not "%lf"? Is that your typo?

Comment: No, actually I did that wrong although the printf in my full programm had it right >>

Comment: When you `printf` `double`, you should use `%f`, not `%lf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scanf("lf",&r);
```

Should be

```
scanf("%lf",&r);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're missing the percent (`%`) symbol in the format string, it should be:

```
scanf("%lf", &r);
```

and then you should add *checking the return value* since, as you just learned, I/O is brittle and can fail. Thus, it's wrong to depend on `r` containing a valid value unless you've verified that the scanning worked:

```
if(scanf("%lf", &r) == 1)
{
  print("got the double %g\n", r);
}
else
{
  printf("**Failed to read a double value!\n");
}
```

Comment: +1 Most educating answer and no rep given. What's wrong with people?

Answer (score 3):

You need `%lf` when you read it in.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
scanf("%lf",&r);
```

You forgot to put in the `%`.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
scanf("%lf", &r);
```

Anytime you use scanf() you need to put the percent sign in front of what type of variable you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `%` before `lf`:

```
scanf("%lf", &yourDouble);
```